# How can I do this effect or pattern in illustrator or photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography

The photo is typography art and I would like to know how to achieve it.

[image: typography effect]

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's actually not so hard :) Such result can be achieved by using a Divide tool (Pathfinder panel) in Illustrator. Please watch a short screencast to show this tool in action:

http://quick.as/AeL8Cnl8x

After that just add some texture to make the poster looking better. Hope this helps :)

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, @Jini :) Please mark this answer is correct if you found it helpful. However, somebody downvoted my answer for no reason.

Comment: How do I do that ? It doesn't allow me to it says to register but I am already